# basic haskell: How to search through a list of lists for an int

Tags: haskell

me again :)

As I said in the title I'm looking for a way to search through a list of lists (of ints) for a particular int.
This is part of a bigger problem but I've simplified it to make it easier to explain in this context.

In this example I'm trying to search through my list of lists of ints to look for the number one. I want it to total up the number of times it finds the number one. In the below example the result would be 3.

Here's what I have so far:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,17,12]
c= [201,16,1]
d = [234,235,123]

y =[a,b,c,d]

getOne :: [[Int]]->Int
getOne List' = total
    where 
        checkNumber x = x==1
            checkList = filter CheckNumber List'
            total = sum checkList
```

I know I can't do this because I can't check if a List is equal to 1 but how can I check a list inside a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without flattening, you can try something like:

```
Prelude> let y = [[1,1,2] , [4], [5,6,1]]
Prelude> sum [length $ filter (==1) yl | yl <- y]
3
```

Or using `Applicative`:

```
Prelude> import Control.Applicative
Prelude Control.Applicative> sum $ length <$> filter (==1) <$> y
```

Answer (score 8):

Flatten your list of lists and reduce this to a problem you already know how to solve. Fundamentally, the fact that you're going through a list of lists does not change your answer: you just care about the number of `1`s in your structure.

You can find the function for flattening a list using [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/). Just enter the type of a function like that, and it will get you the result. It's a very useful tool for learning the Haskell API, so now is a good time to start using it.

It might also be a good idea to implement a flattening function yourself using recursion. Doing this will also give you some insight on how to write the `getOne` function directly. It's a good learning exercise.

Answer (score 0):

I have coded several similar functions of counting for maximization problems. How does this work for your project?

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,17,12]
c= [201,16,1]
d = [234,235,123]

y =[a,b,c,d]
getOne :: [[Int]] -> Int
getOne = length . filter (== 1) . concat
```

Note that the concat method flattens your list, filter evaluates a func for each item in the list and discards any that return false, and length just counts the remaining elements.

Comment: A fine answer, but none of those functions require `Data.List` -- they're all in `Prelude`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fold left option. This is more efficient (iterate over each element once) and no import necessary.

```
getOne :: [[Int]] -> Int
getOne = foldl (\ b a -> if a == 1 then b+1 else b) 0 . concat
```

Comment: Erm this still doesn't work, `a` has the type `[Int]`. Not `Int`